# Flutter: how to internationalise only the CupertinoDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

Is it possible to do internationalise only a specific widget, for example the CupertinoDatePicker (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html)?

My motivation: I'm very happy with the "English" locale of my app, but I need the the CupertinoDatePicker to show months in my native language.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. If you are "very happy with the English locale" for the app, then why would you not be happy with an English date picker? Why would you want an English app with a German date picker (for example)?

Comment: samething i'm finding. likewise I've performed localisation from getx but that isn't enough for cupertinoDatePicker.

Answer (score 2):

This answer isn't the right way to implement but you can get rid out of it. Use CupertinoApp widget, and pass your CupertinoDatePicker into it's builder with desired locale.

```
            CupertinoApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              localizationsDelegates:
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegates,
              supportedLocales: const [
                Locale('en', 'US'),
                Locale('zh', 'CH'),
              ],
              locale: Locale(locale),
              builder: (context, widget) {
                return CupertinoDatePicker(
                  onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
                    setModalState(() {
                      model['dob'] = value.toString();
                    });
                    setState(() {
                      model['dob'] = value.toString();
                    });
                  },
                  maximumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                  dateOrder: DatePickerDateOrder.ymd,
                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                  initialDateTime: DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
                      .parse(model['dob'] ?? '2020-12-10'),
                );
              },
            ),
```

here I assigned stored current locale in `Locale(locale)`. Now this cupertinoDatePicker will pick assigned locale.